# Publish Debug and Release builds to maven local as aars

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, maven-publish

I'm trying to publish an **aar** locally to `/.m2` directory using the `maven-publish` Gradle plugin. With the below code, I can publish the `release` version (with PTML), but not the `debug` one.

I would like to publish either  a `release` or a `debug` one with custom tasks or through command line. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    publishing {
        publications {
            aar(MavenPublication) {

                groupId 'com.sample.project'
                artifactId 'SampleProject'
                version '1.1.0'
                artifact bundleReleaseAar

            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create a new publication for each of your `buildTypes`.

Currently you have only one publication named `library` which uses as the output from the `bundleReleaseAar` task as artifact.

When you want to publish the `debug` version you have to use the output from the `bundleDebugAar` task.

Therefore you need something like this:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            libraryRelease(MavenPublication) {

                artifact bundleReleaseAar
                artifact sourceJar

                groupId 'com.sample.project'
                artifactId 'DummyProject'
                version '1.0'

                pom.withXml {
                    def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                    def dependencies = new ArrayList<Dependency>()
                    dependencies.addAll(configurations.api.allDependencies)
                    dependencies.addAll(configurations.implementation.allDependencies)
                    dependencies.each {
                        if (it.group != null && (it.name != null || "unspecified".equals(it.name)) && it.version != null) {
                            def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            libraryDebug(MavenPublication) {

                artifact bundleDebugAar
                artifact sourceJar

                groupId 'com.sample.project'
                artifactId 'DummyProject'
                version '1.0'

                pom.withXml {
                    def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                    def dependencies = new ArrayList<Dependency>()
                    dependencies.addAll(configurations.api.allDependencies)
                    dependencies.addAll(configurations.implementation.allDependencies)
                    dependencies.each {
                        if (it.group != null && (it.name != null || "unspecified".equals(it.name)) && it.version != null) {
                            def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will create two tasks `publishLibraryReleaseToLocalMaven` and `publishLibraryDebugToLocalMaven`. You can one run them depending on which type you want to publish.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. SInce code inside libraryDebug and libraryRelease are almost similar, is there anyways to reuse the code?

Comment: Sure. That's Groovy code (can also be Kotlin nowadays). You could extract methods/functions if you like.